# Django Non_Field_Error shown duplicated Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, django-forms, bootstrap-4

I've been searching for an answer but any of them are useful for me.
The problem is that I want to show a **non_field_error** with the following code in HTML:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.non_field_errors|join:"<br \>" }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

This, produces the following result:
[The duplicated error, one formatted and the other not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yukOP.png)

This is my **forms.py** code:

```
 user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user or not user.is_active:
            self.add_error(None, "Incorrect credentials")
```

How can I show only the formatted field instead of both?

**UPDATE:**
If I try with this approach:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I have more or less the same problem: [The same error. It appears twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApcaZ.png)

Comment: What does your `form.non_field_errors` look like, if you print it out?

Comment: @RichardStoeffel If I print `form.non_field_errors` it returns `<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>Incorrect credentials</li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

if non_field_errors is a list, instead of joining them with a 
 tag, you can use django's for each syntax, like:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Haven't tested it but thats the general idea and I believe correct syntax

Comment: I have more or less the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem and I found that it's happening because I had `{{ form }}` Django tag this tag is also loading the non_field_errors so I had to render it manually like this

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.label }}
{{ form.field_name }}
```